# Meteor.js two-factor authentication with social login (google, fb, etc)

Tags: javascript, meteor, two-factor-authentication

It's not hard to implement 2FA for a meteor app, it's also super easy to set up social login. But what's an unsolved task for me yet is how to set up 2FA for users with social login? Meteor's social login system doesn't respect such option, and doesn't seem to provide some nice opportunities to implement it. For now any implementation looks like a hack. Perhaps, somebody already faced such problem and could share some approaches/workarounds/ideas on how can I do that?